# Redondear, mostrar y ocultar parte decimal

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-3, scss

¿Como podría redondear y deshacer el redondeo de un número según la opción seleccionada?, y que se vea como este ejemplo:

```js
function redondear(id) {
    $('.btn').css('opacity', '0.6');
    if(id==0){
        $('.round-number').text('14.8');
        $('.btn-secondary').css('opacity', '1');
    }if(id==1){
        $('.round-number').text('15');
        $('.btn-success').css('opacity', '1');
    }
}
redondear(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="redondear(0)">No redondear</button >
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="redondear(1)">Redondear</button>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><p class="round-number">14.8</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

El problema es que se debe aplicar a todos los números de una tabla, que se muestren y oculten las partes decimales al marcar una opción, no se si existe una forma con `CSS`, `jQuery` o de `Bootstrap` para hacer esto.

Investigando leí que también se podría hacer con `SCSS`.

Considero que se podrían guardar los valores en una variable y cambiarlos celda por celda, pero no se si hay otra alternativa. Estoy usando `Bootstrap 3`.

Código del problema:

```js
function redondear(id) {
    $('.btn').css('opacity', '0.6');
    if(id==0){
        $('.btn-secondary').css('opacity', '1');
    }if(id==1){
        $('.btn-success').css('opacity', '1');
    }
}
redondear(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="redondear(0)">No redondear</button >
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="redondear(1)">Redondear</button>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td><p class="round-number">14.8</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">65.2</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">11.1</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">54.2</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">48.6</p></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="round-number">25.1</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">12.9</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">34.5</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">87.3</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">45.4</p></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="round-number">24.8</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">45.2</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">31.1</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">14.2</p></td>
                <td><p class="round-number">78.6</p></td>                
            </tr>
        </table>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Buscas todos los elementos de la tabla que necesitan se redondeados (`eg selector .round-number`)
- Por cada uno de los elementos, buscamos y guardamos el valor inicial de estos en un [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos) ([`$el.data('attr', valor)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/))
- Luego, al llamar a la función `redondear`, por cada uno de los elementos recuperamos el `data-value` y aplicamos (o no) el redondeo ([`Math.round(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round))

#### Ejemplo:

```js
// Buscamos todos los elementos a redondear
let $numbers = $('.round-number');

// Guardamos en el data-attr value el valor inicial
$numbers.each((idx, ele) => {
  let $el = $(ele);
  $el.data('value', $el.text());
});

function redondear(bool) {
  // A cada uno de los elementos
  $numbers.each((idx, ele) => {
    let $el = $(ele),
      val = $el.data('value');
    // Dependiendo de si queremos o no redondear, cambiamos el valor
    $el.text(bool ? Math.round(val) : val);
  });
  
  $('.btn-secondary').css('opacity', bool ? .6 : 1);
  $('.btn-success').css('opacity', bool ? 1 : .6);
}
redondear(false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="redondear(false)">No redondear</button >
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="redondear(true)">Redondear</button>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><p class="round-number">14.8</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">65.2</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">11.1</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">54.2</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">48.6</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p class="round-number">25.1</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">12.9</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">34.5</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">87.3</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">45.4</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p class="round-number">24.8</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">45.2</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">31.1</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">14.2</p></td>
    <td><p class="round-number">78.6</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta perfecto, se aplica a todos los números con la clase `round-number`, incluso si tengo mas tablas con números se aplicará también.